# View diff on Launchpad without proposing a merge

Tags: launchpad

If a propose a branch for merge on Launchpad, it will show a diff with the branch that I have proposed to merge with. I like the way the way that Launchpad shows the diff: is there a way I can view this diff on Launchpad without explicitly proposing the branch for merge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think so. This diff is created with `bzr merge --preview` command and requires 2 branches (source and destination). You can do that locally easily, or you can create a merge proposal and then Reject it.

Comment: I think the bzr merge command only takes one argument, the source. The destination is the current repo.

Comment: @Lorin Hochstein: yes, you're right. But on Launchpad you see merge preview as if your current branch (destination) will be merged to source branch.